# Searching for existence of an element using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have two columns, `BarcodeValuePLC` and `DateTime`, from `dbo.tablename`. Now I want search for a particular Barcode from `BarcodeValuePLC`, which should be ordered with respect to Desc `DateTime`.

I want to do this operation using stored Procedure and return its existence to VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName
(
 @BarCode VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT 
    *
    FROM dbo.tablename 
    WHERE BarcodeValuePLC = @BarCode  
      ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC
END
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that i can search only the top 100 record after sorting

Comment: Before the star add TOP 100

Comment: If the last updated element is present after 100th record then i might miss out the previously updated 100 elements, right?   Then it will be a pblm

Comment: Since we are doing an order by DateTime DESC, The latest updated record will come first. So if you choose TOP 100, then it will return that last Updated 100 rows